# Is it possible to burn DVD as audio CD?

Tags: compact-disc, dvd-burning

Is it possible to burn DVD-R or DVD+R or DVD-RW so that at least SOME devices treat it as audio CD? In principle?

**UPDATE**

I don't mean to burn DVD as DVD so that DVD-aware devices can read it. I mean namely simulate CD having blank DVD?

Comment: "simulate CD having blank DVD" does not make sense to me sorry. It might be a language thing, but what is the real reason you're asking? Please don't cut around the chase, ask about the real problem you're facing and we might be able to help you!

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot. DVD's are formatted a specific way. That's why there are DVD-R and +R and RW. those are all different formats. You cannot treat it as a CD.

CD's are about 700MB in size and DVD's are about 4.7GB in size.

Comment: Yes I know this, but can I FORCE something? May be reformat?

Comment: No, Windows doesn't allow you to. No program does.

Comment: What is the nature of the obstacle?

Comment: @Dims - It's a different laser.  DVD's is significantly narrower.

Comment: @nerdwaller no policeman stays and look after me which laser I use; suppose I can use any laser on DVD while burning and then normal CD laser while reading. What will happen? Nuclear explosion? Enprisonment?

Comment: @Dims Lots of useless discs.

Comment: @Dims the nature of the obstacle is physics.  If you burn a DVD, the tracks will be so narrow that the CD laser can not tell the tracks apart.

Answer (score 4):

the light beams are completely different when reading both media types independently... so no.

Comment: "I don't mean to burn DVD as DVD so that DVD-aware devices can read it. I mean namely simulate CD having blank DVD? " <- my point. still a "no-no" mate.