# Burning Audio CDs from mp3 but on a DVD-R media( not CD-R )

Tags: audio, dvd, compact-disc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to burn DVD as audio CD?](https://superuser.com/questions/518959/is-it-possible-to-burn-dvd-as-audio-cd)

I am trying to create a Audio-CD from mp3 files. The media disc I use is a blank DVD-R disc and **NOT a CD-ROM disc** I used many tools:(CDBurnerXP, Free Audio CD burner,...)
All these tools reject that media and expect only CD-R media. Trying to understand why so? Why can't it burn upto only the capacity of a Audio CD on a DVD-R disc?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to select `Create a Data Disc`, and convert the mp3 files to WAV before burning the disc, any DVD player compatible with LPCM DVD standard will play the files it as long as you stick to 16bit 48kHz. As common WAV files contains PCM audio, converting them to raw PCM is quite easy.

You are better off keeping your mp3's, then burn those to DVD as standard data, not audio. This way you will get about 50 albums/CD's to 1 DVD. You will have to check what codecs your DVD player can play, to determine whether it can play mp3's (most newer ones can) from a DVD.

Comment: thanks. But as I got to know from the earlier post mentioned above, the physics[lasers] and track lengths used in the burning process.